# rails paperclip destroys entire path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

I am using paperclip with Rails 4. When the object is saved, I have the file saved within a particular directory (so it creates the path if necessary):

```
has_attached_file :document, :path => "/:default_document/:documentable/:id/:filename"
```

It works great. However, when I delete the record, it not only deletes the file but the entire path as well. How can I specify to only delete the file and not entire path when I destroy the active record object?

Comment: why you need to keep the path (directories) which would be different for different paperclip objects?

Comment: @RajeshOmanakuttan because this path: /:default_document/:documentable/:id can have more than one file in it.

Comment: Hey, Paperclip will handle that automatically. When you create multiple paperclip objects (files), it will be under different folders inside a parent directory. When you destroy each object, it will remove only the sub-directory containing that file, not the parent directory.